Proving $\left[a_1,\frac{b_1+\sqrt\Delta}2\right]\cdot\left[a_2,\frac{b_2+\sqrt\Delta}2\right]=\left[a_1a_2,\frac{b+\sqrt\Delta}2\right]$
Let $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\Delta})$ be a quadratic field and $\mathcal O$ a quadratic order of $F$ with discriminant $\Delta$. Let
$$\mathfrak{a}_1=\left[a_1,\frac{b_1+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right],\quad \mathfrak{a}_2=\left[a_2,\frac{b_2+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right]$$ be two ideals of $\mathcal O$. Here
$$\Delta=b_i^2-4a_ic_i,\quad i=1,2.$$
Assume that $a_i\in\mathbb N$ and $b_i\in\mathbb Z$ with
$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,\frac{b_1+b_2}{2})=1,$$
how to prove the following statement:
$$\mathfrak{a}_1\mathfrak{a}_2=\left[a_1,\frac{b_1+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right]\cdot\left[a_2,\frac{b_2+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right]=\left[a_1a_2,\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right]$$
where $b$ is any integer satisfying $b\equiv b_i\bmod 2a_i$ for $i=1,2$.
The above is exercise 5.4.8. in Franz Halter-Koch's book: Quadratic Irrationals, page 139.
I can prove this result when $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$. In fact
$$\mathfrak{a}_1\mathfrak{a}_2=\left[a_1a_2,\frac{a_1b_2+a_1\sqrt{\Delta}}{2},\frac{a_2b_1+a_2\sqrt{\Delta}}{2},\frac{\frac{b_1b_2+\Delta}{2}+\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right].$$
Since $b\equiv b_i\bmod 2a_2$, we have that
$$\frac{a_1b_2+a_1\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{a_1(b_2-b)+a_1b+a_1\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\in\mathbb Za_1a_2+a_1\mathbb Z\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}.$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{a_2b_1+a_2\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{a_2(b_1-b)+a_2b+a_2\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\in\mathbb Za_1a_2+a_2\mathbb Z\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}.$$
Thus
$$\mathfrak{a}_1\mathfrak{a}_2=\left[a_1a_2,a_1\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2},a_2\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2},\frac{\frac{b_1b_2+\Delta}{2}+\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right].$$
Let $s=\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}$, we have that
$$\frac{\frac{b_1b_2+\Delta}{2}+\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}
=\frac{s(b_1-b)-2a_1c_1+bs+s\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{s(b_2-b)-2a_2c_2+bs+s\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{s(b_1-b)-2a_1c_1}{2}+s\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{s(b_2-b)-2a_2c_2}{2}+s\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}.$$
If $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$, it is clear that
$$a_1a_2\mid \frac{s(b_1-b)-2a_1c_1}{2}=\frac{s(b_2-b)-2a_2c_2}{2}.$$
Therefore
$$\mathfrak{a}_1\mathfrak{a}_2=\left[a_1a_2,a_1\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2},a_2\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2},s\cdot\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right]=\left[a_1a_2,\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right].$$
The last equality is because $\gcd(a_1,a_2,s)=1$.
My Question: How to prove the general result?

Maybe, in the above exercise, the condition any integer $b$ satifying $b\equiv b_i\bmod 2a_i$ is not enough. We must add the condition $b^2\equiv\Delta\bmod 4a_1a_2$ in order to make sure $\left[a_1a_2,\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right]$ is an ideal. Since $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\frac{b_1+b_2}{2})=1$, we can prove that(See David Cox's Book: The primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$, page 48, Lemma 3.2) there exists a unique integer $b$ modulo $2a_1a_2$ such that
$$b\equiv b_1\bmod 2a_1,\quad b\equiv b_2\bmod 2a_2,\quad b^2\equiv\Delta\bmod 4a_1a_2.$$
For such $b$, we have that
$$\mathfrak{a}_1\mathfrak{a}_2=\left[a_1a_2,\frac{b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}\right].$$
For example, let
$$\mathfrak{a}_1=\left[4,\frac{1+\sqrt{-143}}{2}\right],\quad \mathfrak{a}_2=\left[6,\frac{5+\sqrt{-143}}{2}\right].$$
Here $a_1=4,b_1=1$, $a_2=6,b_2=5$, $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\frac{b_1+b_2}{2})=1$. Solving the equitions
$$b\equiv1\bmod 2\cdot 4,\quad b\equiv 5\bmod 2\cdot 6$$
we have that
$$b\equiv 17,41\bmod 48(=2\cdot4\cdot6).$$
But when $b\equiv 17\bmod 48$, $b^2\not\equiv-143\bmod 96(=4\cdot4\cdot6)$, but when
$b\equiv 41\bmod48$, $b^2\equiv-143\bmod 96$. Therefore
$$\mathfrak{a}_1\cdot \mathfrak{a}_2=\left[24,\frac{41+\sqrt{-143}}{2}\right]\neq \left[24,\frac{17+\sqrt{-143}}{2}\right].$$
In fact, $\left[24,\frac{17+\sqrt{-143}}{2}\right]$ is not an ideal.
